# How to convert an array of objects and arrays of objects to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I have an an array of objects and arrays of objects

```
const a = [[{'k': 'b'}, {'a1': 'c1'}], {'a': 'c'}];
```

And what I want to have is  just array of objects, like

```
const a = [{'k': 'b'}, {'a1': 'c1'}, {'a': 'c'}];
```

I tried to sort out element of `a`, which are arrays (0 element in this example) and pull out objects separately

```
const a_arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
 for(let j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
 a_arr.push(a[i][j]);
 }
}
```

It works fine, but I don't know what must be my second step?
I need to pull out from array just objects (in this case a[1]) and then concat to arrays of object, but how could I achieve this?

Or, maybe there is better way to do all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`Array#reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and concat elements using [**`Array#concat`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
const a = [
  [{
    'k': 'b'
  }, {
    'a1': 'c1'
  }], {
    'a': 'c'
  }
];

console.log(a.reduce((initial, elem) => initial.concat(elem), []));
```